# Maven default locale not same with OS locale

Tags: java, maven, localization

When I type

```
mvn --version
```

in command prompt I see:

> Default Locale : en_US

However my System Locale is `tr_TR`

When I start a Java SE Project without maven and run `Locale.getDefault()`,  `tr_TR` returns fine. But when I run a Maven project and then `Locale.getDefault()` it returns `en_US`  which I do not like.

How can I tell maven that my default locale is TR ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this command

```
set MAVEN_OPTS= -Duser.language=tr
```

Anyway the best solution is to put these informations in the POM file and never by command line. In particular you have to deal with the configuration of **[Maven-Surefire-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/)**

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <user.language>tr</user.language>
                <user.region>TR</user.region>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration> 
    </plugin>
```

***Second Question:***
*Another question if I may, I am running a web app in my locale but it supports lets say german, english.. And your system locale is DE. Can I get your system locale from your request? Or maybe the language you prefer by your browser?*

You can take these informations from the request. Here is an example in a servlet.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GetLocale extends HttpServlet{

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      Locale locale = request.getLocale();
      String language = locale.getLanguage();
      String country = locale.getCountry();

      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      out.println(language + ":" + country);
  }
}
```

Comment: But what if I deploy the project to some other computer with some other Locale? Is there no way to tell Maven to use to OS Locale directly?

Comment: I need to make some searches. I've never faced this problem.

Comment: I've googled but I can't find informations. I think there is no way to tell Maven to use OS locale directly.

Comment: Another question if I may, I am running a web app in my locale but it supports lets say german, english.. And your system locale is DE. Can I get your system locale from your request? Or maybe the language you prefer by your browser?

Comment: Note: I had to specify user.timezone along with language and region to get the full settings for the locale.

Comment: For me `systemPropertyVariables` works only when surefire is configured to run test in fork mode. When run in non-fork mode, `Locale` class is already initialized with "default" locale during JVM startup and cannot be overriden.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
<properties>
    <argLine>-Duser.language=tr</argLine>
</properties>
```

This case works better when the argument is needed at the start of the JVM, as using `maven-surefire-plugin`, your JVM is already running and the arguments won't be reloaded (that was my case using some initialization with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest` to initialize a `MockMvc`).

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to add that I used _argLine_ inside of **configuration**. The docs has a special section for that: [Special VM Properties](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

Defining the property allows you to pass them as command line argument.

This works for me:

```xml
<project>
    <properties>
        <user.language>de</user.language>
        <argLine>-Duser.language=${user.language}</argLine>
    </properties>
</project>
```

```sh
mvn -Duser.language=tr
```