# Rest-Assured Throw HttpResponseException Before Then Statement

Tags: java, testing, automation, cucumber, rest-assured

while doing my API tests, I am getting an error while sending the request before going to the testing phase. This situation occurs in tests that do not return a status code of 2xx. For example, I am getting the following error by Rest-Assured while performing a test where I expect any 404 or 400 results. I could not understand why. Thanks in advance for the support.

Project Link:
https://github.com/mustafamaden/restapi_BDD_examples

Failure Scenario:

```
Scenario: Invalid Grocery
    Given Prepare Url "https://e3f7f8d3-b06d-49ce-825e-8f4e9635fb99.mock.pstmn.io/allGrocery/123"
    When Send Request "GET"
    Then Expected to see 400 status code
```

Log:

```
Step failed
io.restassured.internal.http.HttpResponseException: status code: 400, reason phrase: Bad Request
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:627)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodClosure(MetaClassImpl.java:1048)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1142)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2082)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:495)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:452)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1453)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1202)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1672)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1678)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:173)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:257)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at steps.PrepareRequest.sendRequest(PrepareRequest.java:104)
```

Comment: I  cloned your project, added the failure scenario and ran success. No problem

Comment: Hi, I started to suspect the following situation, after this comment, I wonder if it could be because of the jdk I use or my own pc? I am using mac m1. I have openjdk 17. Could this be caused by a situation? @lucas-nguyen-17

Comment: No, nothing's wrong. I'm using openjdk17 and oracle jdk17.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encounters this problem, project language different than English causes this problem. The actual cause was setting Resource bundle without a country. For us it was Turkish.

1. Setting country alongside with language for Resource Bundle is the actual solution if you need to use.
2. If you don't want to use language support, then setting project language in pom.xml to English works.

To set the project language [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774592/8934747)